# UIWebView - Add an extra parameter to the url request

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Hi I have a url say http://www.foobar.com

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:appURL 
                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:20.0
                ]];
```

Now when this url is formed i can set the urlString to have webtype=iphone

But for every single request that comes from there onwards I need to add webType=iphone to back of the string.

I figured there is some way using

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

But didnt get any solution through it yet... any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, either subclass UIWebView with a simple wrapper that only implements a custom loadRequest or subclass NSURLRequest to change the customURL as JNK said above. It's probably easier to do the later tho.

Answer (score 2):

just create a custiom method returning the cusom url:

```
- (NSURL *)customURLWithPramString:(NSString *)pramString{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.foobar.com?%@&webtype=iphone",pramString]];
}
```

Then you can just go: `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self customURLWithPramString:@"name=123&age=123"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0]];`

where you pass "name=123&age=123" in this case