# UIWebView always add a parameter in url issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am facing an issue in the implementation of `UIWebView` that is I have to add `?app=1`  in all the outgoing url requests. that is when i do a `LoadRequest` in `webView` with http://google.com , it should convert it to http://google.com?app=1 … similarly if it is http://google.com/index.php then it should change it to http://google.com/index.php?app=1

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4380203/1042240) but wasn't able to get the solution..

any help would be great..

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use StringWithFormat method to append @"?app=1" in all the url's before loading a request in web view

Comment: in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` …?

Comment: you should append the string before calling [webview loadRequest:RequestObject], So that your Webview hits for that URL directly.

Comment: Should it add the parameter to every request? So if you clicked on a link or submitted a form in the `UIWebView` should it also add `app=1` to the request parameters or is it just on the request you pass into `loadRequest:`?

Comment: @Popeye YEs on every request the `uiwebview` makes it should have `app=1` appended to it

Comment: I provided an answer that did it both ways in the end so you could make your own mind up which to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like below

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{


    NSString *url=request.URL.absoluteString;

    NSRange extraParam=[url rangeOfString:@"app=1"];
    if(extraParam.location == NSNotFound){
        url=[url stringByAppendingString:@"?app=1"];

        NSURLRequest *newRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [webView loadRequest:newRequest];
    }

  return YES;

}
```

Though the above code is not tested, please try it, if it works.

**Note** - Its just an idea, not solution.

Cheers.

Comment: I did something like this.. just had an extra return statement in the condition.. :)

Comment: This could cause issues. What if you already have a load of parameters already applied to the request and then you go adding `?app=1` on the end, what you would want in that case is `&app=1`.

Comment: Can cause many different bad things like "caching google X scripts and making more requests" or ...etc. And too many "app=1" requests could make application & user interface tired/bored :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add `app=1` to the initial request before you pass it to `loadRequest:` then just do

```
// Based on we don't know what is after http://www.google.com
// there could be other parameters that we aren't aware of.
NSString *urlStr = @"http://www.google.com....";

// Lets search for '?' to see if there are any parameters set already
if([urlStr rangeOfString:@"?"].location == NSNotFound) {
    // There are no parameters already set so we are good and we can just add ours.
    urlStr = [urlStr stringByAppendingString:@"?app=1"];
} else {
    // The request already has some parameters so we want to be adding ours as an additional param
    urlStr = [urlStr stringByAppendingString:@"&app=1"];
}

// Now that we have added our parameter to the request string we can make create the request.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

If you want to append it to every request then try doing the above (with some small amendments) in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` like below

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSString *urlRequestStr =  [[request URL] absoluteString];
    // We need to make sure that we haven't already been passed a request with app=1 on it.
    if([urlRequestStr rangeOfString:@"app=1"].location == NSNotFound) {
        // Lets search for '?' to see if there are any parameters set already
        if([urlRequestStr rangeOfString:@"?"].location == NSNotFound) {
            // There are no parameters already set so we are good and we can just add ours.
            urlRequestStr = [urlRequestStr stringByAppendingString:@"?app=1"];
        } else {
            // The request already has some parameters so we want to be adding ours as an additional param
            urlRequestStr = [urlRequestStr stringByAppendingString:@"&app=1"];
        }

        // Now that we have added our parameter to the request string we can make create the request.
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlRequestStr]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }

    // Continue as normal
    return YES;
}
```

**As someone deems fit to downvote this I will note that this is tested code and works as required by the user. So if you deem fit to downvote please leave a reason why you think this deserves a downvote**

Comment: @Downvoter please give reason for the downvote so I can improve if it needs improving. This is tested code and does as the user requires so why have you downvoted.